# SKNode children with array of classes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to write a method to find children of an SKNode which are of a particular class - but I'm getting an EXC error here

Anyone any ideas about why this might be?

```
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
  func children(#klasses: [AnyClass]) -> [SKNode] {
    var matchedNodes = [SKNode]()
    for child in children as [SKNode] {
      for klass in klasses {
        if child.isKindOfClass(klass) {
          matchedNodes.append(child)
        }
      }

      matchedNodes += child.children(klasses: klasses)
    }
    return matchedNodes
  }

}

class Apple: SKNode {}
class Orange: SKNode {}

let apple = Apple()
let orange = Orange()

apple.addChild(orange)

let fruits = apple.children(klasses: [Apple.self, Orange.self])
```

Error:

Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
extension SKNode {
    func children(#klasses: [AnyObject]) -> [SKNode] {
        var matchedNodes = [SKNode]()
        for child in children as [SKNode]{
            for klass in klasses {
                if child.dynamicType === klass {
                    matchedNodes.append(child)
                }
            }
            matchedNodes += child.children(klasses: klasses)
        }
        return matchedNodes
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! I would upvote your answer but apparently I need a reputation of 15 lol - thanks!